# UITextFieldDelegate textFieldShouldReturn caller

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

Is there a way to detect whether `-[UITextFieldDelegate textFieldShouldReturn]` was called by a user hitting the "Done" key on the keyboard (or equivalent), or if it was called by a programmatic call to `-[UITextField resignFirstResponder]`?

Comment: Confusing question.. Can you elaborate it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the delegate methods to determine whether it is **resignFirstResponder** or **return key** pressed.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField  {

   // here return key pressed will be handled
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

   // used to handle resignFirstResponder

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
     textfieldObject.delegate = self;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:( UITextField * )textField
{
     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this specifically, but you could check the `isFirstResponder` status of the text field. If it is the first responder, you know that the enter key was pressed. Otherwise, you know `resignFirstResponder` was called. This assumes that resignFirstResponder changes the status before calling `textFieldShouldReturn`.